# Handle Orientation Changed on CustomView Two Way Data Binding with Live Data in ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, custom-view, two-way-binding

I'm now creating customview that extends to ContraintLayout with EditText as child View. I have success the Two Way Data Binding on normal case, but when I try to rotate the screen, the edittext not auto set the value from the Live Data. I thought there was a problem with 2 Way Data Binding, but when I try with normal EditText is run normally like what I want to achieve.

```
    class MyEditField @JvmOverloads constructor(
        context: Context,
        attrs: AttributeSet,
        defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
    ) :
        ConstraintLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    
        private lateinit var mEditText: EditText
        private lateinit var mTextViewTitle: TextView
        private lateinit var mTextViewSubtitle: TextView
        private lateinit var mImageViewSubtitle: ImageView
        private lateinit var mTextViewRequired: TextView
        private lateinit var mTextViewError: TextView
        private lateinit var mImageViewError: ImageView
        private lateinit var mImageViewEndIcon: ImageView
        private lateinit var mImageViewStartIcon: ImageView
        private lateinit var mTextViewStart: TextView
        private lateinit var mProgressBar: ProgressBar
        private lateinit var mTextViewSuccessInformation: TextView
        private lateinit var mTextViewSuccess: TextView
        private lateinit var mViewSeparator: View
    
        var text: String = ""
            set(value) {
                field = value
                setTextEditable(value)
            }
    
        @ColorRes
        var textColor: Int = -1
            set(value) {
                field = value
                setEditTextFontColor(value)
            }
    
        var title: String = ""
            set(value) {
                field = value
                mTextViewTitle.text = value
            }
    
        var subtitle: String = ""
            set(value) {
                field = value
                setAndShowHideSubtitle(value)
            }
    
        var hint: String = ""
            set(value) {
                field = value
                setHintText(value)
            }
    
        var requiredText: String = ""
            set(value) {
                field = value
                setRequiredTextView(value)
            }
    
        var startText: String? = null
            set(value) {
                field = value
                setStartTextView(value)
                showHideSeparator()
            }
    
        @ColorRes
        var startTextColor: Int = -1
            set(value) {
                field = value
                setStartTextFontColor(value)
            }
    
    
        var startTextPaddingStart: Int = -1
            set(value) {
                field = value
                setStartTextViewMargin()
            }
    
        var startTextPaddingEnd: Int = -1
            set(value) {
                field = value
                setStartTextViewMargin()
            }
    
        var isRequired: Boolean = false
            set(value) {
                field = value
                showHideTextRequired(value)
            }
    
        var errorText: String? = null
            set(value) {
                field = value
                setAndShowHideError(value)
            }
    
        var successText: String? = null
            set(value) {
                field = value
                setAndShowHideSuccessText(value)
            }
    
        var successInformationText: String? = null
            set(value) {
                field = value
                setAndShowHideSuccessInformationText(value)
            }
    
        var inputType: Int = EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL
            set(value) {
                field = value
                setInputTypeEditText(value)
            }
    
        @DrawableRes
        var endIcon: Int = -1
            set(value) {
                field = value
                setAndShowImageEditText(value)
            }
    
        var endIconTint: ColorStateList? = null
            set(value) {
                field = value
                setImageViewEndIconTint(value)
            }
    
        @DrawableRes
        var startIcon: Int = -1
            set(value) {
                field = value
                setAndShowImageStart(value)
                showHideSeparator()
            }
    
        var startIconTint: ColorStateList? = null
            set(value) {
                field = value
                setImageViewStartIconTint(value)
            }
    
    
        var isLoading: Boolean = false
            set(value) {
                field = value
                showLoading(value)
            }
    
        var enabledInput: Boolean = true
            set(value) {
                field = value
                setEnabledEditText(value)
            }
    
        var imeOptions: Int = EditorInfo.IME_NULL
            set(value) {
                field = value
                setImeOptionEditText(value)
            }
    
        var isAllCaps: Boolean = false
            set(value) {
                field = value
                setFiltersInternal()
            }
    
        var maxLength: Int = -1
            set(value) {
                field = value
                setFiltersInternal()
            }
    
        var isPassword: Boolean = false
            set(value) {
                field = value
                setInputAsPassword(value)
            }
        init {
            val v = inflate(context, R.layout.layout_my_edit_field, this)
            v?.let {
                assignView(it)
            }
            context.theme.obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.MyEditField,
                defStyleAttr,
                0
            ).apply {
                title = getString(R.styleable.MyEditField_title) ?: ""
    
                subtitle = getString(R.styleable.MyEditField_subtitle) ?: ""
    
                hint = getString(R.styleable.MyEditField_hint) ?: ""
    
                requiredText = getString(R.styleable.MyEditField_requiredText) ?: "*"
    
                errorText = getString(R.styleable.MyEditField_error)
    
                endIcon = getResourceId(R.styleable.MyEditField_end_icon, -1)
    
                endIconTint = getColorStateList(R.styleable.MyEditField_end_icon_tint)
    
                isLoading = getBoolean(R.styleable.MyEditField_is_loading, false)
    
                successText = getString(R.styleable.MyEditField_success)
    
                successInformationText = getString(R.styleable.MyEditField_success_information)
    
                text = getString(R.styleable.MyEditField_text) ?: ""
    
                textColor = getResourceId(R.styleable.MyEditField_text_color, -1)
    
                startText = getString(R.styleable.MyEditField_start_text)
    
                startTextPaddingStart =
                    getDimensionPixelOffset(R.styleable.MyEditField_start_text_padding_start, -1)
    
                startTextPaddingEnd =
                    getDimensionPixelOffset(R.styleable.MyEditField_start_text_padding_end, -1)
    
                startTextColor = getResourceId(R.styleable.MyEditField_start_text, -1)
    
                startIcon = getResourceId(R.styleable.MyEditField_start_icon, -1)
    
                startIconTint = getColorStateList(R.styleable.MyEditField_start_icon_tint)
    
                enabledInput = getBoolean(R.styleable.MyEditField_enabled, true)
    
                inputType = getInt(
                    R.styleable.MyEditField_android_inputType,
                    EditorInfo.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL
                )
                imeOptions =
                    getInt(R.styleable.MyEditField_android_imeOptions, EditorInfo.IME_NULL)
                isPassword = getBoolean(R.styleable.MyEditField_is_password, false)
                this.recycle()
            }
    
    
        }
    
    
        private fun setStartTextFontColor(value: Int) {
            mTextViewStart.setTextColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(
                    context,
                    if (value == -1) R.color.black_text else value
                )
            )
        }
    
        private fun setEditTextFontColor(value: Int) {
            mEditText.setTextColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(
                    context,
                    if (value == -1) R.color.black_text else value
                )
            )
    
        }
    
        private fun setFiltersInternal() {
            val arrayOfInputFilters = arrayListOf<InputFilter>()
            if (isAllCaps) arrayOfInputFilters.add(InputFilter.AllCaps())
            if (maxLength > -1) arrayOfInputFilters.add(InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength))
            if (arrayOfInputFilters.isNotEmpty()) mEditText.filters = arrayOfInputFilters.toTypedArray()
        }
    
        private fun setEnabledEditText(value: Boolean) {
            mEditText.enableView(value)
            (mEditText.parent as LinearLayoutCompat).enableView(value)
        }
    
    
        private fun setAndShowHideSubtitle(value: String) {
            mTextViewSubtitle.text = value
            if (value.isEmpty()) {
                mTextViewSubtitle.gone()
                mImageViewSubtitle.gone()
            } else {
                mTextViewSubtitle.visible()
                mImageViewSubtitle.visible()
            }
        }
    
        private fun showHideTextRequired(value: Boolean) {
            mTextViewRequired.visibility = if (value) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
        }
    
        private fun setStartTextViewMargin() {
            var paddingStart = mTextViewStart.paddingStart
            var paddingEnd = mTextViewStart.paddingEnd
            if (startTextPaddingStart != -1) {
                paddingStart = startTextPaddingStart
            }
            if (startTextPaddingEnd != -1) {
                paddingEnd = startTextPaddingEnd
            }
            mTextViewStart.setPadding(
                paddingStart,
                mTextViewStart.paddingTop,
                paddingEnd,
                mTextViewStart.paddingBottom
            )
        }
    
    
        private fun setAndShowHideError(value: String?) {
            mTextViewError.text = value
            if (value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                mTextViewError.gone()
                mImageViewError.gone()
            } else {
                mTextViewError.visible()
                mImageViewError.visible()
            }
        }
    
        private fun setAndShowImageEditText(@DrawableRes value: Int) {
            if (value != -1) {
                mImageViewEndIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, value))
                mImageViewEndIcon.visible()
            } else {
                mImageViewEndIcon.gone()
            }
        }
    
        private fun setAndShowImageStart(@DrawableRes value: Int) {
            if (value != -1) {
                mImageViewStartIcon.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, value))
                mImageViewStartIcon.visible()
            } else {
                mImageViewStartIcon.gone()
            }
        }
    
        private fun setImageViewEndIconTint(value: ColorStateList?) {
            mImageViewEndIcon.imageTintList = value
        }
    
        private fun setImageViewStartIconTint(value: ColorStateList?) {
            mImageViewStartIcon.imageTintList = value
        }
    
        private fun showLoading(value: Boolean) {
            if (value) {
                mProgressBar.visible()
            } else {
                mProgressBar.gone()
            }
        }
    
        private fun setAndShowHideSuccessText(value: String?) {
            mTextViewSuccess.text = value
            if (value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                mTextViewSuccess.gone()
            } else {
                mTextViewSuccess.visible()
            }
        }
    
        private fun setAndShowHideSuccessInformationText(value: String?) {
            mTextViewSuccessInformation.text = value
            if (value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                mTextViewSuccessInformation.gone()
            } else {
                mTextViewSuccessInformation.visible()
                mTextViewSuccessInformation.updateLayoutParams<LayoutParams> {
                    marginStart = if (value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        0.pxTodp()
                    } else {
                        context.resources.getDimensionPixelOffset(R.dimen.dimens_4dp).pxTodp()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        private fun showHideSeparator() {
            if (startIcon != -1 || !startText.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                mViewSeparator.visible()
            } else {
                mViewSeparator.gone()
            }
        }
    
    
        private fun setRequiredTextView(value: String) {
            mTextViewRequired.text = value
        }
    
        private fun setStartTextView(value: String?) {
            mTextViewStart.text = value
            if (value.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                mTextViewStart.gone()
            } else {
                mTextViewStart.visible()
            }
        }
    
    
        private fun setHintText(value: String) {
            mEditText.hint = value
        }
    
    
        private fun setTextEditable(value: String) {
            mEditText.setText(value)
        }
    
        private fun setInputAsPassword(value: Boolean) {
            mEditText.transformationMethod =
                if (value) PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance() else null
        }
    
        private fun setInputTypeEditText(inputType: Int) {
            mEditText.inputType = inputType
        }
    
    
        private fun setImeOptionEditText(value: Int) {
            mEditText.imeOptions = value
        }
    
    
        private fun assignView(v: View) {
            mEditText = v.findViewById(R.id.my_et)
            mTextViewTitle = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_title)
            mTextViewSubtitle = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_subtitle)
            mImageViewSubtitle = v.findViewById(R.id.iv_subtitle)
            mTextViewRequired = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_required)
            mTextViewError = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_error_edit_text)
            mImageViewError = v.findViewById(R.id.iv_error_edit_text)
            mImageViewEndIcon = v.findViewById(R.id.iv_edit_text)
            mProgressBar = v.findViewById(R.id.progress_loading)
            mTextViewSuccess = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_success_edit_text)
            mTextViewSuccessInformation = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_information_success_edit_text)
            mImageViewStartIcon = v.findViewById(R.id.iv_left_et)
            mTextViewStart = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_left_et)
            mViewSeparator = v.findViewById(R.id.v_et_split)
        }
    
        fun getEditText(): EditText {
            return mEditText
        }
    
    
    }
```

Here my code the BindingAdapter

```
object MyEditFieldBindingAdapter {
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter(value = ["app:textAttrChanged"])
    fun MyEditField.setListener(
        textAttrChanged: InverseBindingListener?
    ) {
        if (textAttrChanged != null) {
            getEditText().addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun beforeTextChanged(
                    charSequence: CharSequence,
                    i: Int,
                    i1: Int,
                    i2: Int
                ) {
                }

                override fun onTextChanged(
                    charSequence: CharSequence,
                    i: Int,
                    i1: Int,
                    i2: Int
                ) {
                }

                override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable) {
                    textAttrChanged.onChange()
                }
            })
        }
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("app:text")
    fun MyEditField.setText(value: String) {
        val old = this.getEditText().text.toString()
        if (old != value) {
            this.getEditText().setText(value)
        }
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "app:text", event = "app:textAttrChanged")
    fun MyEditField.getText(): String {
        return getEditText().text.toString()
    }
}
```

For the implement
*activity.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.android.example.TestViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".pages.nonfasoprospect.NonFasoProspectActivity">

        <com.android.example.MyEditField
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:end_icon="@drawable/ic_calendar"
            app:error="@string/lunas"
            app:required="true"
            app:requiredText="*"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            app:start_text_padding_end="@dimen/dimens_16dp"
            app:start_text_padding_start="@dimen/dimens_16dp"
            app:start_text="+62"
            app:subtitle="@{viewModel.editLiveData1}"
            app:text="@={viewModel.editLiveData1}"
            app:title="Test 1" />

        <com.android.example.MyEditField
            android:id="@+id/test2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:error="@string/lunas"
            app:required="true"
            app:requiredText="*"
            app:start_icon="@drawable/ic_calendar"
            app:enabled="false"
            app:subtitle="@{viewModel.editLiveData2}"
            app:title="Test 2" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@={viewModel.editLiveData2}"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_test"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{viewModel.editLiveData1 +` ` +viewModel.editLiveData2}" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
</layout>
```

MyActivity.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyActivity : BaseActivity<ActivityMyBinding>() {

    private val viewModel by viewModels<MyViewModel>()

    override fun setBindingViewModel() {
        super.setBindingViewModel()
        getViewBinder().viewModel = viewModel
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        getViewBinder().test.getEditText().addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
            override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
                if (p0.toString()
                        .startsWith("0") && (p0?.length ?: 0) > 1
                ) {
                    try {
                        if (p0.toString().toDoubleOrNull() == 0.0) {
                            getViewBinder().test.setText("0")
                        } else {
                            getViewBinder().test.setText(p0.toString().substring(1))
                        }
                    } catch (_: Exception) {

                    }
                }
            }

        })

        viewModel.editLiveData1.observe(this){
            Log.d("OBSERVE", it)
        }
        Log.d("TEST", viewModel.editLiveData1.value.toString())
    }

    override fun getLayoutId(): Int {
        return R.layout.activity_my
    }
}
```

Before rotate
[image: before rotate]

After rotate (only the EditText that set value as live data)
[image]
Is there any wrong with my customview or binding adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Aaah, I found it. I just have to set `EditText.isSaveEnabled = false`